# border:outset; only working in firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, border

i have a table on [this page](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/minesweeper.html) with the following css (each `td` has the class `box`)

```
.box{
    border: 3px outset #959595;
    width:25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border: 4px inset #444;
}
```

i get what i want in firefox

[image: firefox]

but in any other browser it doesnt seem to be working as i want it to

[image: chrome]

Comment: Not using a border style from the 90s would solve a lot of problems

Comment: @Bojangles good point, thats why i never use `inline-block`, or `width`/`height`. and obviously not really outdated things like `<style>`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation on `border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) (re: `outset`):

> Displays a border that makes the box appear in 3D, embossed. It is the opposite of `inset`. When applied to a table cell with `border-collapse` set to `collapsed`, this value behaves like `ridge`.

Your table has `border-collapse: collapse;`, so it's actually rendering as `border-style: ridge` in Firefox.

Either set `border-collapse: separate;` or set `border-style: ridge;` to normalize the style across browsers that may not be changing `outset` to `ridge`.