# Border style ridge is not working in chrome and safari browser

Tags: html, css

border style ridge is working in Firefox browser but not working in chrome and safari.how to fix this problem.

Comment: Post the CSS that you are trying to use. Also mention the browser version. For me, it works fine both on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: you can refer this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137342/borderoutset-only-working-in-firefox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137554/3143384 see this answer

Comment: border: 6px ridge black;

Comment: 5.1.7 safari browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="module">
<div>
.module {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f06d06;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid blue;  
  margin: 20px;
}
.module:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

using with webkit....
try this..

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find the exact reason why, but it isn't that your `ridge` property isn't working. It seems that the algorithm that the `ridge` property uses to determine the other color besides black, to actually show the ridge in the border, is causing there to be no difference in color.

I'd say Firefox is actually enforcing a different color besides black, because my color is darker than the black.

I used a dark grey color as a test and then the ridge shows up.

**Instead of black I would use a slightly lighter tone for chrome and safari.**

```
div {
border: 6px #151513 ridge;
}
```